# add admob to android application error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, admob

I have an error;  reklam cannot be resolved or is not a field
my code in activity.java

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.reklam);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this,AdSize.BANNER,"a14f58fce51e76f");
    layout.addView(adView);
```

my main.xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/reklam"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

Comment: do you have the necessary jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Best tutorial for Step by Step Admob Integration.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals